# How to disable code popups when ctrl-clicking in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I ctrl-click on something, I want to open the implementation/definition, but VSCode shows instead a popup with code preview, so that I have to do one more click to get to the place. How to disable this behavior and get VSCode to open the location immediately?

Comment: Is it Alt+Click? I can't remember if I customized this on mine, but that seems to do what you want while Ctrl+Click does nothing.

Comment: What OS are you using? I imagine the shortcuts are different on Mac.

Comment: It seems to be working ok here, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvkzh.gif , so maybe you need to disable a plugin ?  (created on Windows 11, with VSCODE version 1.80.1, and ScreenToGif))